# Excel Pivot - Have a Pivot of Pivots (or anyhow a % based on value of one pivot on another)

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

My question is:

- I have a Pivot reporting Counts of issues, whatever state
- I have another Pivot, same source, reporting only those in a specific
  state

I'd like to create a Pivot reporting the percentage of the ones in a specific state based on that total count.

Like:

```
Pivot 1          Pivot 2         MyNeed

A    10          A   2           A   20%
B    20          B   5           B   25%
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you may include in your question a portion of your source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a picture-based howto, use the ideas so it suits your needs.

Pivot table:

[image]

Source data:

[image]

Configuration:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Great!! This worked. I never thought about using the same value in this way, Row and Column. Thanks a mill!

Comment: Yes, done. But I'd liek t oexpand a bit the question. How can I change the percentage to the recripocal, like showing 20% instead of 80% ?

Comment: @Maurizio I recommend to create a new question. It is a Q&A site and your new question in your comment is a completely new one and different from the original. Thus all the users may benefit from this and it is better searchable. And make your question please more detailed, with providing the source data table and an exact expected result, which you may create in Excel as a mock up and insert the screenshot.